# Open Application in App Link outside of receiver

Tags: java, android

When using App Links, the receiver app (EX. Whatsapp) is paused, and your application's activity is opened on top of the receiver app.

For example, if you open your link from a WhatsApp's chat page, the new activity isn't opened from your app (The WhatsApp's task in recent apps includes your app), while your app isn't in the recent task.

But what if I want to open my application in a new task? Separate from the receiver app?

This is my Manifest file of the activity opened from the App Link:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Activitys.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="eventtk.uae-dc.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/product/"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Is there a thing I should add to the IntentFilter?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you would like to achieve, but you can try
to add

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

to your activity definition.

More information here: 
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en